# Please, please don't show me my own suggested edits in the 10k bar

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

I recently passed 2k on a public beta site, getting me the moderator tools.

I'm quite active in suggesting tag wiki edits, and it bugs me to no end when the little brown circle has a 4 in it, but I can't review them.

Could you please only show me edits I can do something with? Please?